# What byte order when BitConverter.IsLittleEndian = false

Tags: c#, bitconverter

I'm storing numbers in their byte equivalent format, using the least number of bytes possible. With the range 65535 through 16777215, BitConverter gives me a 4 byte array, but I want to only store 3 bytes.

For the code below, my array is [0]254, [1]255, [2]255, [3]0, so I can chop out byte [3]. This is on a Core i7 proc. In my production code, before the array copy, I am checking BitConverter.IsLittleEndian to determine that I can chop the last byte.

```
int i = 16777214;
byte[] bytesTemp = BitConverter.GetBytes(i);

byte[] value = null;
if (BitConverter.IsLittleEndian) 
    Array.Copy(bytesTemp, 0, value, 0, 3);
```

My question is - do I need to concern myself with the Endian-ness of the system, or does the CLR just use this LittleEndian format regardless? I don't have a BigEndian system (nor even know how I'd get one) to test whether my byte array comes out in the reverse order.

Comment: It depends on the computer architecture, most architectures are LittleEndian. However, .Net code can run on BigEndian architectures - the .NET Micro Framework can run on big-endian. Version 4.1 added  support for big-endian.

Comment: I hope you're not doing this to try to save space.

Comment: If space is your concern - you could consider things like "varint"; this takes 1 byte for 0-127; 2 bytes for 128-16,383; 3 bytes for 16,384 to 2,097,151; 4 bytes for 2,097,152 to 268,435,455; and 5 bytes for 268,435,456 to 4,294,967,295 (assuming unsigned, etc) - and has defined endianness (/cc @Rawling) (actually, 5 bytes takes you all the way to 34,359,738,367 - if you really need it)

Comment: @MarcGravell - the only reference to I can find to varint is this [link]http://pastebin.com/Qk7LXESQ?

Comment: @winnt93 it is an encoding detail from "protocol buffers"; here: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding#varints - basically, it uses 7 bits data, and the 8th bit as a continuation flag; [example reader](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/ProtoReader.cs#L1105-L1136); [example writer](https://github.com/mgravell/protobuf-net/blob/master/protobuf-net/ProtoWriter.cs#L539-L552)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, according to the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter(v=vs.110).aspx), you need to be concerned.  They have an example where they reverse the bytes if the architecture is not the desired endianess.

As far as where to get a BigEndian system, I think that the ARM based processors are big-endians, although I haven't tested this.  So if you're running on Win RT device or a phone, for example, you might get different behavior.

Comment: Itaniums are big-endian too, although IIRC they can run individual processes litle-endian if needed, and again IIRC: when running .NET they always end up being little-endian

Comment: This basically answered my question - yes I need to be concerned and I'd missed that bit in the MSDN docs (so I now have a check and an array.reverse when required). However, @MarcGravell made reference to varint, which was also helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It entirely depends on what you are doing with the data. If you are going to be writing it to disk for portable persistence, then yes... I would probably care about endianness. If you are just going to use it to recreate an `int` later in the same process (or on the same machine), it probably doesn't matter as much.

However, when I *do* need to worry about endianness, I usually don't acheive that by `BitConverter` *at all* - personally, I'd be tempted to use byte masking and shifting; then you don't even need to *know* the endianness - it'll work the same on any system. It also avoids the annoyingly bad design decision of `BitConverter` *returning* a byte array rather than *accepting* an array and offset.

For example:

```
byte[] buffer = ...

// write little-endian
buffer[offset++] = (byte)(i & 0xFF);
buffer[offset++] = (byte)((i >> 8) & 0xFF);
buffer[offset++] = (byte)((i >> 16) & 0xFF);
buffer[offset++] = (byte)((i >> 24) & 0xFF);
```

Comment: Might be getting a little bit of off-topic here, but why are you saying it's a bad decision to create and return the array rather than accept it?

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis unnecessary array allocations; in most scenarios where you want the bytes of a value, you are already working with local buffers - it would be nice to be able to use: `BitConverter.GetBytes(i, buffer, offset);`

Comment: `It entirely depends on what you are doing with the data` - well, he's trying to remove redundant `0` bytes, so I'm pretty sure he *should* be caring about endianness.